# Example of too few commas(,) in an introductory phrase?

Tags: american-english, commas

This sentence popped up as correct on a website:

"Even though I enjoyed myself at the expensive dinner and most of my friends were in town to see me, I left."

I'm no grammarian, so I turn to you all for help. Shouldn't there be a comma before *and*?

"Even though I enjoyed myself at the expensive dinner**,** and most of my friends were in town to see me, I left."

I assume that since "and most of my friends were in town to see me" is an independent clause, it should have a comma at the beginning.

I'm a grammarphobe. Please answer correctly, but gently.

Comment: Either is acceptable, I believe.  Nevertheless, I recommend omitting the comma.  In this case, your sentence is short for *Even though I enjoyed myself at the expensive dinner and **even though** most of my friends were in town to see me, I left.*  Considering that putting a comma before *and* cuts that clause off from the *even though* on which it depends, I advise not using it.

Comment: They have two different meanings.

Answer (score 1):

"Most of my friends were in town to see me" looks like an independent clause at first glance, but it's actually a subordinate clause of "I left." Since both are related to "even though," I would leave out the comma.